# Gradient using PIL is just one solid color

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, gradient

I made a little script to create a gradient using python and save it as an image. Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Define the image size and color gradient
width, height = 500, 500
color_start = (255, 0, 0)  # red
color_end = (0, 0, 255)  # blue

# Create a new image with the given size
image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))

# Draw a gradient background on the image
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
for y in range(height):
    color = tuple(int(color_start[j] + (color_end[j] - color_start[j]) * y) for j in range(3))
    draw.line((0, y, width, y), fill=color)

# Save the image to a PNG file
image.save("gradient.png")
```

However, instead of having a gradient I have a solid color (blue) and one tiny line of red at the top. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to devide by `height` : `color = tuple(int(color_start[j] + (color_end[j] - color_start[j]) * y / height) for j in range(3))`. Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

Rather than drawing hundreds of lines, you might find it more intuitive to use the built-in [linear_gradient()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.linear_gradient) function which gives you a 256x256 linear gradient:

```
from PIL import Image

# Generate Red, Green and Blue bands individually
G = Image.new('L', (256,256))       # 256x256, black, i.e. 0
B = Image.linear_gradient('L')      # 256x256, black at top, white at bottom
R = B.rotate(180)                   # 256x256, white at top, black at bottom

# Merge and resize
grad = Image.merge("RGB",(R,G,B)).resize((512,512))
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome ! I didn't think about it thanks !